# C-Lightning update 0.6 doc

Tags: lightning-network, full-node, core-lightning

How do you update safely to 0.6 the working C-Lightning node?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to update C-Lightning?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/77804/what-is-the-proper-way-to-update-c-lightning)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just stop the old version, download the new binaries, unpack them, and run them. On the first start `lightningd` will take care of updating the database if necessary and

Alternatively you can also compile the binaries yourself, like you did before the release:

```
git clone https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning.git /opt/lightning
cd /opt/lightning
./configure --disable-developer --disable-valgrind
make 
sudo make install
```

Afterwards `lightningd` and `lightning-cli` will be in your `$PATH` and available from everywhere.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I would like to keep my existing data/config. Will I keep them following the steps you wrote above?

Comment: Yes, the database is migrated to the new version automatically, and you should not have to change anything. The one exception may be if you have `--addr` in the commandline or `addr` in the config, that option got split into `bind-addr` and `announce-addr`.

Comment: thank you!
however a problem has occurred when making the source:
gossipd/gossip.c: In function ‘find_local_update’:
gossipd/gossip.c:1702:7: error: implicit declaration of function ‘structeq’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   if (structeq(scid, &i->scid))
       ^~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
<builtin>: recipe for target 'gossipd/gossip.o' failed
make: *** [gossipd/gossip.o] Error 1
what do you think the problem could be?
thank you in advance!

Comment: version: GNU Make 4.1

Comment: ok so the problem is that structeq was updated 3 days ago and the code was not updated in gossip.c file... actually the header file hasnt even been included