# What is the proper way to update C-Lightning?

Tags: core-lightning

I downloaded the latest github .zip for version 0.6 and unpacked it but when I check the version I am running it returns:

```
v0.5.2-2016-11-21-1644-g1616fcb
```

Any idea what I did incorrectly? What's the proper way to update C-Lighting from the terminal in Ubuntu?

Comment: When you run it, what command are you using? Did you build and install 0.6 in the same location your path points to?

Comment: You can see which binary executes by using `which lightningd`. Like @MeshCollider mentions, this is likely due to the old binary being executed instread of the new one

Comment: I am using this command to run it: lightningd/lightningd --network=bitcoin --log-level=debug --ipaddr=$my_ip --alias=someNode. Sorry I am very new to this. All I did was download the latest .zip file from the github and unpacked it in my existing lightning folder that has the previous binary. What should I do differently? TIA

Comment: Is there a `lightning` in your directory? You might have nested the installations. The simplest way to solve it is to move/remove the origin directory and unzip the release in a new directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted the original folder and installed from scratch.